# Why does simpleblobdetector missed this blob?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have been using simple blob detector in opencv but was puzzled today regarding why would the largest blob being missed in blob detector. I've ensured all parameters conducting filtering has been turned off. The following are my code spinet and keypoints reported by simple blob detector.

[image: Raw Image]

[image: Keypoints reported]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
particlefilterparams = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
particlefilterparams.filterByArea = False
particlefilterparams.minArea=7
particlefilterparams.maxArea =99999999
particlefilterparams.filterByCircularity = False
particlefilterparams.minCircularity = 0
particlefilterparams.maxCircularity = 255
particlefilterparams.filterByConvexity = False
particlefilterparams.minConvexity = 0
particlefilterparams.maxConvexity = 1
particlefilterparams.filterByInertia = False
particlefilterparams.minInertiaRatio = 0
particlefilterparams.maxInertiaRatio = 1
particlefilterparams.minThreshold =1
particlefilterparams.maxThreshold = 255

shotdetector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(particlefilterparams)
counter = 0

diff = cv2.imread('Missed.png', 0)
ret,bimg = cv2.threshold(diff, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
oimg=cv2.bitwise_not(bimg)
shots = shotdetector.detect(oimg)
oimg = cv2.bitwise_not(oimg)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(oimg, shots, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just to let you know I will provide you an answer after the Christmas holidays cuz I'm also having similar issue "missing out on debris detection" in an image. (In addition, I'll remove this comment after posting explanation and working code).